# Outlook 2010 IMAP only keeps latest 2 days, want to keep 2 months?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

I'm using Outlook 2010 on my laptop. My account is set up as IMAP because I don't want this to be independent of the server.

However, it only shows the last few days of mail, and while on the road I frequently need to refer to mail a little older than that.

I'm looking for a way to have it sync the past two months, but haven't found a way.

Answer (score -1):

You can save offline mails upto a year.

You simply have to change your settings in your outlook mail. Here is the answer for your question " https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-how-much-mail-to-keep-offline-f3a1251c-6dd5-4208-aef9-7c8c9522d633 "

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that info is for an Exchange Server account, which this is not, and it's for Outlook 2013/16, not 2010. So...I'm still lost at finding any control I can set.  Thanks!

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as are "hello" comments and pleading for feedback. You should stick to the point of the question and quote the relevant information from your link, using your own words if possible. Please read how to [reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).